# How to find out how a program was removed?

Tags: 16.04, apt, uninstall, telegram

Is there a way to see how a program was removed? In this case I had telegram installed on ubuntu 16.04 and now its not there, running

> cat /var/log/apt/history.log | grep telegram

did not return any results. Possibly I agreed to remove it when installing another package but I wanted to confirm if that was the case and if not why it happened. Im not certain but I think it was originally installed by running

> sudo apt-get install telegram

Answer (score 0):

Your `apt/history.log` gets rotated and archived, meaning roughly every month the logfile gets compressed and stored as `/var/log/apt/history.log.X.gz`, where X is an incrementing number, 1 being the newest archive.

To also search the older, compressed archives for the string `telegram`, you can use `zgrep` which is capable of automatically uncompressing files before matching, if needed:

```
zgrep telegram /var/log/apt/history.log*
```

Comment: zgrep telegram /var/log/apt/history.log* did not return anything, I dont know the exact date I used it last but it would have been in the last couple days. So it should have been in the uncompressed log. Is there anywhere else I could check?

Comment: Not that I know, if it got removed by apt it should be in there. You could also check the `term.log*` files in that directory, but I doubt this will return anything then either.